# Ajax запрос в контролеру

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, mvc

привет есть запрос

```
function update(value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/Test",
            type: "POST",
            data: value,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#data").text(data);
            }
        })
    }
```

Контролер

```
public ActionResult Test(string value)
        {
            return View(value);
        }
```

Визуально не чего не происходит  но в инспекторе Chrome пишет что сервер ответил ошибкой 500 Internal Server Error

Запрос происходит при вводе в input

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { }))
    {

        @Html.TextBox("list", null, new { @class = "sort", @oninput = "update(this.value)", @parametr = "this.value" });

    }
```

UPDATE
Сменил тип метода на string

```
public string Test(string value)
        {
            return value;
        }
```

Вроде значение возвращает и оно пишется в div но оно не отображается на странице

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Параметр в методе контроллера называется `value`. Привязка параметров к данным запроса происходит по именам параметров/ключам данных запроса. Чтобы это работало (без дополнительных действий), имена-ключи должны совпадать.

Но ошибка на сервере, скорее всего, была вызвана отсутствием представления (view) `Test` или ошибкой внутри него (`return View(value);`).

```
function update(aValue) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Test",
    type: "POST",
    data: {value: aValue}, // !!!
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("In success:");
      console.log(data);
      $("#data").text(data);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log("In error: " + textStatus + " - " + errorThrown);
      console.log(jqXHR);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.А почему именно `value : value`

Comment: @Санитариум Параметр в методе контроллера называется `value`. Привязка параметров к данным запроса происходит по именам параметров/ключам данных запроса. Чтобы это работало (без дополнительных действий) имена-ключи должны совпадать.